# cant append javascript

Tags: javascript

Почему я не могу сделать append двум элементам сразу ?
26 и 27 строчка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Если данный дочерний элемент является ссылкой на существующий узел в документе, то функция appendChild() перемещает его из текущей позиции в новую позицию" — https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild . Вам нужно создавать отдельный элемент для каждой вставки.

Comment: ааа, понял, спасибо